Run background task in vscode
I have a bash script that starts elasticsearch (./scripts/dev/start_elasticsearch.sh).
if I launch this script in a normal shell and at the end of it I close the shell Elasticsearch will still run in the background.
However if i create a task in my vscode tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Start Elasticsearch",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "./scripts/dev/start_elasticsearch.sh",
            "group": "none",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "clear": true
            },
        },
    ]
}

ES starts, but then it's killed again at the end, and doesn't run in background.
I tried different other options like:
    {
        "label": "Start Elasticsearch",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "./scripts/dev/start_elasticsearch.sh",
        "group": "none",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "always",
            "panel": "dedicated",
            "clear": true
        },
    }

or
    {
        "label": "Start Elasticsearch",
        "type": "process",
        "command": "./scripts/dev/start_elasticsearch.sh",
        "group": "none",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "always",
            "panel": "dedicated",
            "clear": true
        },
    }

but without success.
do you know how i can achieve this?
Many thanks
kind regards
